# Calcular año de nacimiento según la edad actual? usando java android

Tags: java, android, date

Estoy intentando calcular el año de nacimiento a partir de la edad que el usuario tiene, ya tengo la función que calcula la edad pero ahora busco el proceso inverso:
aquí la función que uso para calcular la edad:

```
public static String getAge(int yearOfBirth, int monthOfBirth, int dayOfBirth) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate birthdate = LocalDate.of(yearOfBirth, monthOfBirth, dayOfBirth);
        Period p = Period.between(birthdate, today);
        return "Tengo " + p.getYears() + " años, " + p.getMonths() + " meses, " + p.getDays() + " días de edad.";
    } else {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new Date());
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        Calendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar(yearOfBirth, monthOfBirth, dayOfBirth);
        Calendar c1 = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
        long end = c2.getTimeInMillis();
        long start = c1.getTimeInMillis();
        long milliseconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(Math.abs(end - start));
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeInMillis(milliseconds);
        int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1970;
        int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - 1;

        return "Tengo " + mYear + " años, " + mMonth + " meses, " + mDay + " días de edad.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Había pensado en una solución convirtiendo la fecha actual en milisegundos con el Calendar, restando los años, meses y días en milisegundos, y luego convertirla a Calendar, pero tu necesitas algo más completo porque tienes que considerar los años que tienen 366 días y si por ejemplo tienes una fecha como 31/12/1980, cuando hagas la resta seguro te arrojará 1981, por no considerar los años que tienen 366 días.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con el método add de [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,%20int)) **add(int field,int amount)**, te da la fecha exacta de nacimiento, por lo que a la fecha actual le resto los años, meses y días, al resultado le sumo uno al mes  porque Enero empieza con 0, Calendar.JANUARY=0 y CALENDAR.DECEMBER=11 y a los días también dado que el mes el día 1 es 0, por lo que en el ejemplo siguiente te daría la fecha exacta del cumpleaños suponiendo que la edad es **48 años 1 mes y 2 días**, la persona habría nacido el **29 de Septiembre de 1970**:

```
    //Fecha de nacimiento 29/09/1970 
    int aniosEdad   = 48; //al dia actual 31/10/2018
    int mesEdad     = 1; //al dia actual 31/10/2018
    int diasEdad    = 2; //al dia actual 31/10/2018

    //Fecha actual 31/10/2018
    Calendar calendarioActual = Calendar.getInstance();


    //Le resto la edad
    calendarioActual.add(Calendar.YEAR, -aniosEdad);
    calendarioActual.add(Calendar.MONTH, -mesEdad);
    calendarioActual.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -diasEdad);


    System.out.println(calendarioActual.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    System.out.println(calendarioActual.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
    System.out.println(calendarioActual.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+1);
```

El resultado es:

1970

9

29

Answer (score 0):

Espero sea esto lo que buscas.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(sdf.format(getBornDate(22, 9, 13))); //Resultado = 1996-09-13
    System.out.println(sdf.format(getBornDate(23, 4, 6))); //Resultado = 1995-04-06
    System.out.println(sdf.format(getBornDate(22, 11, 1))); //Resultado = 1996-11-01
    System.out.println(sdf.format(getBornDate(52, 2, 9))); //Resultado = 1966-02-09
}

/**
 * Dado los años cumplidos, el mes y el día de nacimiento
 * se debe obtener la fecha de nacimiento.
 *
 * @param anosCumplidos
 * @param mes
 * @param dia
 * @return fecha de nacimiento
 */
public static Date getBornDate(int anosCumplidos, int mes, int dia) {
    //Se obtiene la fecha en la que el usuario cumplio años, considerando el año en curso
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, mes - 1);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dia);
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, c.get(Calendar.YEAR) - anosCumplidos);

    return c.getTime();
}
```

Esta funcion (getBornDate) regresa un objeto Date con la fecha de nacimiento, dado los años cumplidos y el mes y día.

Saludos!